# Running python within flash actionscript (AS2 preferably)

Tags: python, flash, actionscript

Suppose I have a python script, say my_script.py. Now in flash actionscript(version 2), I want to run this script. For example, when a certain button is clicked, a certain function in my_script.py is executed (i.e the parameters are entered into the function via input text box or some other input method, and the variable returned by the function is stored in some other variable within flash actionscript). For example, say in the python script we have a function add(p, q)

> def add(p, q):
>
> ```
>    return p+q
> ```

and I want to import this code into action script, and there write a code which enters the parameters p an q to that function, and another variable (say sum) stores the value of add(p, q).

> //Code to import the function
>
> //sum= add(a, b)

I know this question is a bit vague, but it is the best way I could put it. I don't know whether it is possible either. I would be gratified if someone helps.

Answer (score 1):

> You can prefer this web link about how to use python + Actionscript...
>
> [PyAMF - AMF for Python][1]
>
> [1]: http://www.pyamf.org/tutorials/actionscript/simple.html